# Xcode 7 linker error with cocoapods

Tags: ios, xcode, bitcode

I use xcode 7 and cocoapods to work with parse and my app runs correctly on simulator but when I want to test it on my iPhone5s this error appears:
ld: -undefined and -bitcode_bundle (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE=YES) cannot be used together
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either remove the "-undefined" linker flag or disable Bitcode.

If you don't have a good reason to use "-undefined", you should get rid of this:

> Project Settings -> Target -> Build Settings -> Other Linker Flags -> delete the "-undefined" entry.

Else disabling Bitcode is the way to go:

> Project Settings -> Target -> Build Settings -> Enable Bitcode -> set to "No".

Comment: thank you for your response but I couldn't find other linker flags.I searched in build settings but there isn't.On the other hand when set Enable bitcode to no app after a while crashes.

Comment: Have you tried to search for Other Linker Flags using the search field in the top-right corner of Build Settings? Also make sure you have the filter set to **All** instead of **Basic** in the top-left area. Finally, the linker flags entry might also appear as `OTHER_LDFLAGS`. Concerning the crash: please post the log output.

Comment: thank you I found Other Linker Flags and the crashes were related to something else.

Comment: @dr_barto what does the `-undefined` flag _mean_ though? I'm having a similar problem, but the solution above did not resolve it.

Comment: Ah, I figured it out. It instructs the linker on what action it should take when it encounters an undefined symbol [(source)](https://glandium.org/blog/?p=2764). In my project, the value specified is `dynamic_lookup`, meaning defer finding the symbol until runtime.